# SQL DMV linking Index Usage to Stored Procedure Usage

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm auditing & cleaning some SQL 2008 R2 Boxes.

I'm doing a lot of work with:

```
sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats (Index usage)

sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats (Procedure usage)
```

These DMVs provide a lot of good performance information.

What I need is a way of linking the results together. i.e. How do I figure out which Stored Procedures are using which indexes?

I've been shredding the XML in the plan cache, but this is very inefficient, does anybody have a better solution?

Comment: This is what I use to find sprocs using a specific index before I drop them. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/finding-what-queries-in-the-plan-cache-use-a-specific-index/

Comment: Hi, I've already looked at this. My problem is that I have over 80,000 indexes on the smaller boxes, so I'd have to shred each plan cache for each index. I'm trying to come up with something more efficient that I can run every day enabling me to persist the results to a permanent table and monitor changes. I've gotten as far as shredding each plan once and getting a list of indexes it uses, but I'm hoping for some little-known dmv or XML trick that produces minimal overhead.

Comment: 80,000 indexes? In the words of Buddy the Elf, that's shocking.

Comment: Why you need information which procedure use specific index? To know which statement use index isn't enough (with statement it's short way to get information which procedure use these statements)?

Comment: Deadsheep39: I've inherited a vast In-house solution which is massively and inappropriately indexed. I need to figure out which stored procedures are generating the most overhead i.e. Index Scans & Updates, and then feed that back to the appropriate Development teams. (I need to identify the problem parts of the System and drive ownership back to the correct teams.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `system reports`.

In *Management studio* right click on server or specific database. Select *Reports* and then *Standard reports* and select **Object execution statistics**.

I'm sure you are able to catch queries (if it's necessary) `with SQL Server Profiler`.